# Play Json.writes ignore case class property

Tags: scala, playframework, jackson, play-json

I have a property in a case class Foo which I don't want to serialize. 
However, it's a complicated case class and if possible I'd like to use the automatic Json.writes macro to serialize it.
Is it possible to annotate a property in the case class to ensure it is not serialized

```
case class Foo(
  serializeMe: String,
  ignoreMe: String
)


val toSerialize = Foo("value1", "Value To Be Ignored")
Json.writes[Foo].writes(toSerialize)
```

This should serialize to

```
{
  "serializeMe": "value1"
}
```

I tried:

```
case class Foo(
  serializeMe: String,
  @JsonIgnore ignoreMe: String
)
```

and also

```
case class Foo(
  serializeMe: String,
  @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY) ignoreMe: String
)
```

None of these seem to be respected by the macro. 
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this approach: [Play Framework - how to ignore some fields for Json Serialisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089851/play-framework-how-to-ignore-some-fields-for-json-serialisation)

However, it would require to manually describe serialization of all other fields, which leads to some boilerplate..